# Filter array inside array?

Tags: javascript

I have this structure :

[image]

Now what i want is to filter through items and find result.

This is my .ts:

```
search(event) {
    let b = this.autocompletedata.filter( a => a.items['item']? a.items['item'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
    console.log(b,'result');
}
```

Any suggestion what im doing wrong ? I always get empty result

Comment: Don't use the same identifier `a` for the variable where you store the result and the variable in the private function inside `filter()`.

Comment: ok i changed that but i get empty results again

Comment: Second, the `filter()` function expects a boolean value. So you should return `false` instead of empty string in case your item doesn't match.

Comment: i updated ... but still nothing

Comment: But the actual reason why it doesn't work is that `a.items['item']` is always undefined because `a.items` is an array and inside the brackets you need a number of the element you want to look for. You need to iterate over the `a.items` array.

Comment: a is an indexed array or associative ?

Comment: @mrid as you can see in the screenshot it is an indexed array

Comment: oh okay....missed it...updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
 search(event) {
     let b;

     a.forEach(function(entry) {
         b = this.autocompletedata.filter( entry => entry['item']? entry['item'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
     });

     console.log(b,'result');
 }
```

Comment: what is "a" here ?

Comment: `a` is your array

Comment: this.autocompletedata.forEach(function(entry) {
         b = this.autocompletedata.filter( entry => entry['item']? entry['item'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
         console.log(entry,'entry');
     });

If i do like this because autocompletedata is my array i get this error: Property 'autocompletedata' does not exist on type
 'void'.